# Select Spinner item value

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

So I have this spinner where I want to find what the selected item is. I got something in place to remember what the item which is selected. Now there is a button to click within the same layout where the spinner is, this will bring up a dialog box which tells which item you have selected. But I am getting error , on my log cat it says "java.lang.NullPointerException"

This is my XML file for the Dialog Box;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffc0c0c0">

<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Saving&apos;s Account"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSelectedText"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/transferaccount_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java file which is for the dialog ;

```
public class examplefile extends DialogFragment {

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View theDIalog = inf.inflate(R.layout.makea_transfer_confirm, null);
    builder.setView(theDIalog);

    builder.setCancelable(true);

return dialog;

}

}
```

Now this is the screen that you get when you start off - well after the main activity class but I don't want to share the code from main activity since i believe it's not necessary;

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.makea_transfer, container, false);


    spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinnermakeatransfer);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.accounts,R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("Select an item");



Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinnermakeatransfer);
    String spinnerSelectedItem = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();


    TextView spinnerText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectedText);
    spinnerText.setText(spinnerSelectedItem);

return v;

}
```

Now this is the makea_transfer XML ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnermakeatransfer"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please can someone help me fix this issue, please comment if you don't understand or need more details from me.

This is the Log Cat 
[Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pdwbp3wx08j7et/logcat.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
TextView spinnerText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectedText);
```

`spinnerSelectedText` is inside `makea_transfer_confirm` layout but trying to get from `makea_transfer` :

Get TextView in `onCreateDialog` method of `examplefile` DialogFragment :

```
View theDIalog = inf.inflate(R.layout.makea_transfer_confirm, null);
builder.setView(theDIalog);
// get TextView here
 TextView spinnerText = (TextView) theDIalog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectedText);
```

And for showing `spinnerSelectedItem` value in `spinnerText` pass it using `examplefile` class using setArguments :

```
v.findViewById(R.id.maketransferReviewButton).setOnClickListener(
                                                new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
  SampleDialog fragment = new examplefile(); 
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString("spinnerText", spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
  fragment.setArguments(args);
  examplefile.show(getFragmentManager(), "make a transfer dialog"); 
 } 

});
```

and inside onCreateDialog get String using getArguments as:

```
String strSelectedValueFromSpinner = getArguments().getString("spinnerText");
View theDIalog = inf.inflate(R.layout.makea_transfer_confirm, null);
builder.setView(theDIalog);
// get TextView here
TextView spinnerText = (TextView) theDIalog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectedText);
spinnerText.setText(strSelectedValueFromSpinner);
```

Comment: Yes you are right, so inside the examplefile java how would I be able to change that text and replace it with the spinner value ?

Comment: @user3511639: see my edit answer. let me know if still any issue

Comment: THink you cahnged it while I send that comment so I will quickly read what you typed.

Comment: I am not acutally following what you said there abot the constructor part, do I put that code in the examplefile . java or in the other java file ?

Comment: @user3511639: yes add it inside examplefile . java

Comment: so when I add that method in that examplefile. java file I am getting this error; "Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment # set Argument (bundle) instead"

Comment: @user3511639: please show code how  you are using `examplefile` class to show alert

Comment: this is a link the examplefile.java [Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nbsv8m65caha9g/examplefile.txt?dl=0)

Comment: @user3511639: where you are creating object of `examplefile` class to show Dialog?

Comment: v.findViewById(R.id.maketransferReviewButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MakeaTransferConfirm makeaTransferConfirm = new examplefile();
                examplefile.show(getFragmentManager(), "make a transfer dialog");
            }
        });
this code is in the other java file that I have

Comment: @user3511639: see my edit answer and why down-voted my question?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed that button

Comment: I am sorrry to bother you, but  i got an error on this line ; args.putString("spinnerText", spinnerText);                                                           This is the error I get ; [Error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygif7mrx36s3zwm/error.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String spinnerSelectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.i("Selected item : ", items);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
```

and Delete

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinnermakeatransfer);
```

Comment: Yeah that does print out which item I have selected on to the console. But I want that text to print inside this dialog box I have got

Comment: @user3511639 You only need to pass the spinner text item into the Alert Dialog's Constructor and use setText to set the Text.