# Android AsyncTask passing values

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment, android-location

I want to obtain the users current location within a DialogFragment and pass all data to a SQLite databse. In my DoInBackground I get the current location which is working perfectly

I want to set a TextView of long and lat, how can I pass the value out my AysncTask and back to my dialog

```
 protected getLocation doInBackground(String... params) {
```

}

```
    protected void onPostExecute(getLocation result) {

    }
    }
```

I want to pass the value in the outer class so I can put the data in sql

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){


    final AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.insert_long);
    text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.insert_lat);
    build.setView(view);

    db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    db.open();
    build.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking for.
Do you want to return the location from the AsyncTask?
If so you could just change the return type of the AsyncTask from `String... params` to `Location... params`

Comment: I want to return long and lat so I can set them as TextView and store them into SQLite through onClick. db.insert() is a method in my DBhelper

Comment: Can you post code of how you are calling your asynctask?

Comment: @Mark - This is not complete code, as I couldn't find line on your `LocationTask ` execute() and what is `control`?

Answer (score 0):

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
   background computation.
3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

So you need pass Double[] or your custom structure wraping lat,lon as result.

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Double[]>
```

And implement `onPostExecute(Double[] result)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the return type of the method `doInBackground(...)` when declaring the class.
Like this:

```
private class LocationReceiver extends AsyncTask<String, Void, double[]> {
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        LocationManager loca = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        return new double[] {longitude, latitude};
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(double[] resultArray) {
   // Do something with the returned location
   double lon = resultArray[0];
   double lat = resultArray[1];
}
```

}

Comment: I only wanted to simply get the users current location as it slowed down my main thread, so now I want to pass Long and lat back into my Dialog

Comment: I updated my answer. You could also create a simple POJO class that contains only latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class with latitude and longitude variables :

```
class LatLng {
   public final  double latitude;
   public final  double longitude;

   LatLng(double latitude, double longitude) {
       this.latitude = latitude;
       this.longitude = longitude;
   }
}
```

Now  return `LatLng` object from `doInBackground` method for getting both values in `onPostExecute` method:

```
protected LatLng doInBackground(String... params) {
        ...
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
  return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

}
```

And change `LocationTask` class as:

```
private static class LocationTask extends AsyncTask<Location,
                                             Void, getLocation> {

    ....
    @Override
    protected getLocation doInBackground(String... params) {  
     // your code here

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(getLocation result) {

        text = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        text.setText(result.latitude +"--"+result.longitude);
    }
  }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html

Comment: will you write that using my code, I dont quite understand

Comment: @user370305: both is right either use custom class or default LatLng class instead of returning `Location` object

Comment: @Mark: then what is issue?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK After DoInBackground obtains long and lat I want postexecute to set my TextView as the Long and Lat, and how can i call on long and lat to be in my db.insert() method

Comment: it wont recognize getApplicationContext() and on my onClick to get the lat and long what will I call?

Comment: @Mark: use `context` instead of `getApplicationContext()` and where you are showing DialogFragment please show code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thank you for your help, I have updated my code now, Also what do i call to get lat and long to be placed? in my insert method within onClick?

Comment: @Mark: where you are showing DialogFragment please show code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I should have mentioned that, I have a fragment with a listview and button and when the button is clicked it should call my task fragment and the user enters all data while the location is automatically obtained and put with every new task added which is what im trying to do

Comment: @Mark: Ok see my answer in following post [Select Spinner item value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076564/select-spinner-item-value/29076738#29076738)

Comment: @Mark: let me know if you have still any issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have a problem with             }
                //Required return value here
            return new getLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        } with wont recognize location

Comment: @Mark: declare `Location location` outside `doInBackground` method

Comment: Ok last thing, Im trying to set a textView..on my dialogFragment how can I pass it back to my dialog so it reads long and lat this is what I wrote but it didnt work and how can I pass the long and lat back to my dialog fragment so it inserts it to db. Ill update my code

Comment: @Mark: see  this post for passing dialog fragment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076564/select-spinner-item-value/29076738#29076738

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Ive updated my code, and I have read the link. But is there not a way for me to pass the values long, lat back in the onClick? If you look at my code